# HTTP PUT with base64 encoded attachment using requests

Tags: python, base64, python-requests

I'm using `requests` to perform an HTTP PUT on a file, but for some reason, it is uploading the raw ASCII and not base64-encoding it first.

```
files = {'file': ('mydata.csv', open('mydata.csv', 'rb'))}  
...  
try:
    logging.info("Upload URL: " + insert_upload_url)
    headers = {'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
    upload_res = requests.put(insert_upload_url, files=files,
                              data={'insertUpload': data}, headers=headers)
    logging.info("Status: " + str(upload_res.status_code))
    if upload_res.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        logging.info("Reason: " + upload_res.reason)
    else:
        logging.info("Response: " + upload_res.text)
except Exception as e:
    logging.info("Error: " + e.message)
```

When I dump the raw HTTP request, I see that the data is not being encoded as `application/octet-stream` and not in base64:

```
PUT /apibatchmember/services/rest/batchmemberservice/G9X7CsNn3HisxFdwAu4W76mBewUkQcKD_limGK1MDZ-eW3-olsn8HW0l5oePvEU_ZwHaPbEz2_c1YonjauDs7Jhk9DGvGNSTLMbgSSY9TGVuk00I_-tKPw8mjoXzC63YsFzBIYIeYXHKf34dYxmmhz4iSeDw/batchmember/insertUpload HTTP/1.1
Host: api.example.com
Content-Length: 5062
Content-type: multipart/form-data
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/1.2.3 CPython/2.7.5 Darwin/12.5.0

--5f934d42eabb4d7abe8bdef2cea94b6b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="insertUpload"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<insertUpload>
    <criteria>LOWER(EMAIL)</criteria>
    <fileName>email.csv</fileName>
    <separator>,</separator>
    <fileEncoding>UTF-8</fileEncoding>
    <skipFirstLine>false</skipFirstLine>
    <dateFormat>mm/dd/YYYY</dateFormat>
    <mapping>
        <column>
            <colNum>0</colNum>
            <fieldName>CUSTNUM</colNum>
        <column>
        <column>
            <colNum>1</colNum>
            <fieldName>FIRSTNAME</colNum>
        <column>
        <column>
            <colNum>2</colNum>
            <fieldName>LASTNAME</colNum>
        <column>
        <column>
            <colNum>3</colNum>
            <fieldName>EMAIL</colNum>
        <column>
    </mapping>
</insertUpload>
--5f934d42eabb4d7abe8bdef2cea94b6b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="email.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

\xef\xbb\xbf1045,Janice,Waddell,blah@example.com
1156,Scott,Sheldon,blah@example.com
1267,Adrianus,Lengkeek,blah@example.com
1295,EDWIN,ODIFE,blah@example.com
1345,Albert,Stephenson,blah@example.com
...

--5f934d42eabb4d7abe8bdef2cea94b6b--
```

How can I get that `text/csv` part to be a base64-encoded stream?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I am getting the correct attachment header now using the following:

```
with open('/Users/mark.richman/email.csv', 'rb') as fd:
     b64data = base64.b64encode(fd.read())

files = {'file': ('email.csv', b64data, 'application/octet-stream')}
```

However, I still don't get `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` in the file attachment header. Any idea?

**UPDATE 2**

I had to hack in the header as such: `files = {'file': ('email.csv', b64data, 'application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64')}`

I see the header in the HTTP Dump, but I am still getting back `HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type`.

**UPDATE 3**

It looks like `requests` needs an API update to support what I'm trying to do here. The first part of the multipart (the XML data) needs to have `Content-Type: text/xml` set, and the API currently doesn't support this. Discussion over [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/1640).

Comment: Thanks for your 2nd update - solved my problem as it got the header in there for me and now my integration works. Not ideal, but functional!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do

```
import base64


response = requests.put(url, data={'insertUpload': base64.b64encode(data)}, files=files, ...)
```

You don't define `data` though so if you're attempting to use a file object then this will not work.

If `data` is a string then this will work fine.

---

I misunderstood your question initially.

So if you're not trying to avoid loading the whole file into memory (which it seems like you are), you could just do

```
with open('mydata.csv', 'rb') as fd:
     b64data = base64.b64encode(fd.read())

files = {'file': ('mydata.csv', b64data, 'application/octet-stream')}
requests.put(...)  # everything here is the same as what you did
```

On the other hand if you're looking to encode the data without loading it entirely into memory then there is no existing method for this. For the entire contents to be base64 encoded correctly it needs everything in the file first. Consider (for example) the following:

```
print(base64.b64encode('line\n'))
# => bGluZQo=
print(base64.b64encode('line\nline\n'))
# => bGluZQpsaW5lCg==
```

They are related but they're not capable of simply being concatenated. You might have better luck scoping the issue at hand to just using making a File-like object that will base64 encode text on the fly and such. Good luck!

Comment: I don't need to encode `data` I need to encode the attached csv file.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't scroll down your request content far enough. As far as I know there is no way to base64 encode a CSV file as it is being read. You could encode it ahead of time and then use the file method you're using above. I'll update my answer with more possibilities though.

Comment: That worked, but I had to set the MIME type in the files dict. However, I still don't get "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" in the file attachment header. Any idea?

Comment: We don't support sending arbitrary headers just yet but we're discussing it [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/1640)